# T-test with conditional data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, t-test

I have some data giving the vital signs of people before and after one experiment. Also for each single measurement I have some informations about the subject that could affect the results and need to be taken into account. How can I take more variables into account for the t-test? Is it possible?

Comment: please indicate nature of your measurements (e.g. continuous or numeric , count data or  ). Several techniques are available for if you have a number of variabes.

Comment: vital signs like heart beat, breath, pressure, before and after the experiment, that's for a t-test. I also have crosses of a questionary (Sad, Curious Angry etc) and a level of happiness from 1 to 5

Comment: state purpose of analyisis